# How to pause/resume a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

*Background:* I wrote a custom container which is capable of holding three fragments. Depending on the state of this container only two or those three fragments are visible. To inform fragments that their visibility was changed I tried out two options:

1. I called [Fragment.setUserVisibleHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint%28boolean%29) method with respective value. Hosted fragments overrode this method and react appropriately. This worked out.
2. I called [FragmentTransaction.hide()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide%28android.app.Fragment%29) and [FragmentTransaction.show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show%28android.app.Fragment%29) methods to hide and show fragments. Hosted fragments overrode Fragment.onHiddenChanged() and reacted as needed. This worked out as well.

My problem is that I am not satisfied with either of these options. I would like to put invisible fragment into a standard *paused* state. Advantage of this option is that I keep the code clean and simple, as I don't need to override any special methods (like `setUserVisibleHint()` or `onHiddenChanged()`) and I can handle everything inside `onPause()` and `onResume()` which are already implemented.

*Question:* What is the proper way to put a fragment into a *paused* state and then to resume it from that state?

**Update:** I tried out `FragmentTransaction.detach()` too. This is not an option because it destroys the view, which is not allowed in my case.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your this? I have exactly the same problem. `FragmentTransaction.hide()` does not call `onPause` which is causing some strange effects in such a case...

Comment: @mixable After some deeper research it turned out, that it is impossible to put it into paused state without detaching (removing) it.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want to call [FragmentTransaction#attach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#attach%28android.app.Fragment%29) and [FragmentTransaction#detach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#detach%28android.app.Fragment%29) to put your fragment through the life-cycle routines the same as FragmentPagerAdapter ([see source here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java)).

Detaching the `Fragment` with `detach()` will put the `Fragment` through the `onPause`, `onStop` and finally `onDestroyView` life-cycle methods, and then when you re-attach it with `attach()` it will go through `onCreateView`, `onStart` and finally `onResume` life-cycle methods.

You must make sure you are using tag's as-well as container-id since you can have multiple fragments attached to a single container and you will have to be able to get the `Fragment` reference from the `FragmentManager` which will then have to be done via its tag.

Comment: I want to have something similar but without destroying the view.  Otherwise all animations will be sluggish. In fact I want to have just pause/resume only. It's very weird they didn't offer this option.

Answer (score 4):

[FragmentTransaction.setMaxLifecycle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction?hl=en#setMaxLifecycle(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.State)) method can be used for this purpose. To pause a fragment just set its maximum state to `STARTED`:

```kotlin
// hide and pause the fragment
transaction.hide(fragment)
transaction.setMaxLifecycle(fragment, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)

// show and resume the fragment
transaction.setMaxLifecycle(fragment, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
transaction.show(fragment)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect! Never knew about that method setMaxLifecycle() o_O But there is a fly in the ointment - you can't force fragment to onStopped status, only onPaused or onViewDestroyed